# Apache2 - display auth only for public IP's, only on testing server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to configure universal `.htaccess` file for my application to protect my testing server. I want to display basic auth for any request that comes from public IP, only if current server is testing.

How to archieve this? I know how to protect domain and exclude some IP:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthUserFile /some/path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy any
```

But how I can let this code run only if server is dev/testing? I can't change env variables. I thought about detecting domain (server that I want to protect is on subdomain), and place code from above in some sort of `if` block, but I don't know how.

Comment: If these are 2 different hosts and just keep this code only for dev/testing

Comment: @anubhava htaccess file is in Git repo and I'm using it to deploy to prod and testing server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `mod_setenvif` to set an env variable based on current host and use it `auth` later:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^sub\.domain\.com$ SECURED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthUserFile /some/path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from env=SECURED
Satisfy any
```